# Mysql from command line: execute sql code and then sql script

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I want to execute some "sql code" and then sql script that uses mysql user defined variables that I set in the "sql code".

I try from the command line (bash):

```
mysql -e "sql code" < script.sql
```

but only "sql code" gets executed. Is there a neat way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move things around with `cat -` and pipe.

```
echo "sql code" | cat - script.sql | mysql
```

The hyphen `-` tells cat to pass standard in to standard out and since its the first argument it'll wait until standard is finished before sending `script.sql`